# How to add an additional space to the latter element in a list Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of strings and I hope to add an additional space to the latter element in it.

```
my_list = ['AA',
           'BB', 
           'CC', 
           'DD']
```

my expected outputs:

```
my_list = ['AA',
           ' BB', 
           '  CC', 
           '   DD']
```

I only know how to add space to each element using the code below:

```
[' '+i for i in my_list[1:]]
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can get the expected result with list_comprehension and `enumerate()`:

```
my_list = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
new_list = [" "*i + el for i, el in enumerate(my_list)]
# > ['AA', ' BB', '  CC', '   DD']
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is using a for loop:

```
my_list = ['AA',
           'BB', 
           'CC', 
           'DD']

for i in range(0,len(my_list)):
    my_list[i]= " " * i + my_list[i]

print(my_list)
```